# Error connecting to localhost:8060: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: java, port, bigdata, apache-spark

I'm new to Apache Spark.

I'm receiving data at my UDP port 8060, I want to capture it and perform
some operations in the real time, for which I'm using Spark Streaming. While
the code seems to be correct, I get the following output:
https://gist.github.com/d34th4ck3r/0e88896eac864d6d7193

I'm using the following command:

```
mvn  -e -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8080 tomcat:run exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="twoGrams.Main"
```

Also, `$netstat -pn | grep 8060` 
return nothing. Hence the port is free.

For example, another system is sending my UDP data at port 8060 as 1;2;3;4.. and I want to parse it on the basis of ";" and print 1 2 3 4.. using Spark Streaming in real time.

I think the problem may be because of the interval within which the Spark is
trying to connect the port is too short, but I'm not sure how to change it
and if that actually is the problem.

Comment: It's unclear to me what storm is supposed to do, what spark streaming is supposed to do and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @maasg  I mistyped Storm. I meant Spark. I have corrected the question accordingly and added an example.

Comment: could you post the code as well?

Comment: is this "spark" thing configured to run on *8060* port on its own, or is it supposed to be available as an application inside Tomcat, which you seem to be running on *8080*?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my gist(https://gist.github.com/d34th4ck3r/0e88896eac864d6d7193) to show my code after writing custom receiver and the log after that. It loops fine, but when I send the data to the port, it stops looping and gives some error, I couldn't make sense out of.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have modified the code from `SocketInputDStream`, it [creates a stream socket](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/SocketInputDStream.scala#L71), that is a TCP socket. You want a datagram socket (UDP). You need to create your own SocketReceiver ([see the guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html))

Comment: Hi, I have updated my gist(gist.github.com/d34th4ck3r/0e88896eac864d6d7193) to show my code after writing custom receiver and the log after that. It loops fine, but when I send the data to the port, it stops looping and gives some error, I couldn't make sense out of.

Comment: As [you noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042415/using-apache-spark-for-udp), it's a different question.